# Sympy -- AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'right'

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to build a simple pendulum model in `sympy`.

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error?

The tutorial is here:

http://for.rest/articles/The-Spring-Pendulum-with-Sympy/

Here's the code. Note, I modified my code slightly because the tutorial picked a very unintuitive coordinate system(+y pointing down).

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, init_printing
import sympy.physics.mechanics as me
init_printing()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pydy.system import System
from numpy import linspace
%matplotlib inline

# Create the variables
L, theta = me.dynamicsymbols('L theta')

# Create the velocities
L_dot, theta_dot = me.dynamicsymbols('L_dot theta_dot')

# Create the constants
m, g, t, L_0 = sympy.symbols('m g t L_0')

# Create the world frame
A = me.ReferenceFrame('A')

# Create the pendulum frame
B = A.orientnew('B', 'axis', [theta, A.z])

# Set the rotation of the pendulum frame
B.set_ang_vel(A, theta_dot * A.z)

# Create the Origin
O = me.Point('O')

# Create the mass point
P = O.locatenew('P', L * -B.y)

# Display the mass point location in the A frame
P.pos_from(O).express(A)

# Set origin velocity to zero
O.set_vel(A, 0)

# Create the velocity of the mass point
P.set_vel(B, L_dot * -B.y)
P.v1pt_theory(O, A, B)

P.vel(A).express(A)
```

The problem arises in the last line of code there. Note, the object `P.vel(A)` is type `sympy.physics.vector.vector.Vector`, which has `express` as a method.

Here's the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    691                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    692                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 693             printer.pretty(obj)
    694             printer.flush()
    695             return stream.getvalue()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    363                 if cls in self.type_pprinters:
    364                     # printer registered in self.type_pprinters
--> 365                     return self.type_pprinters[cls](obj, self, cycle)
    366                 else:
    367                     # deferred printer

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\interactive\printing.py in _print_plain(arg, p, cycle)
     66         """caller for pretty, for use in IPython 0.11"""
     67         if _can_print_latex(arg):
---> 68             p.text(stringify_func(arg))
     69         else:
     70             p.text(IPython.lib.pretty.pretty(arg))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\pretty.py in pretty(expr, **settings)
   2162 
   2163     try:
-> 2164         return pp.doprint(expr)
   2165     finally:
   2166         pretty_use_unicode(uflag)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\pretty.py in doprint(self, expr)
     60 
     61     def doprint(self, expr):
---> 62         return self._print(expr).render(**self._settings)
     63 
     64     # empty op so _print(stringPict) returns the same

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\vector\vector.py in render(self, *args, **kwargs)
    283                                 pform = vp._print(
    284                                     ar[i][0][j])
--> 285                             pform = prettyForm(*pform.right(" ",
    286                                                 ar[i][1].pretty_vecs[j]))
    287                         else:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'right'
```

This creates a separate issue because, without expressing this, I can't run a computation later.

```
pendulum = me.Particle('pend', P, m)

gravity = m * g * A.y
forces = gravity 

kane = me.KanesMethod(A,
                      q_ind=[L, theta],
                      u_ind=[L_dot, theta_dot],
                      kd_eqs=[L_dot - L.diff(t),
                      theta_dot - theta.diff(t)])
```

Which produces this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-aeb1b3bb40e8> in <module>()
----> 1 fr, frstar = kane.kanes_equations([(P, forces)], [pendulum])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\mechanics\kane.py in kanes_equations(self, bodies, loads)
    537                     'kinematic differential equations to use this method.')
    538         fr = self._form_fr(loads)
--> 539         frstar = self._form_frstar(bodies)
    540         if self._uaux:
    541             if not self._udep:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\mechanics\kane.py in _form_frstar(self, bl)
    332             v = [msubs(vel, self._qdot_u_map) for vel in vlist]
    333             return partial_velocity(v, self.u, N)
--> 334         partials = [get_partial_velocity(body) for body in bl]
    335 
    336         # Compute fr_star in two components:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\mechanics\kane.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    332             v = [msubs(vel, self._qdot_u_map) for vel in vlist]
    333             return partial_velocity(v, self.u, N)
--> 334         partials = [get_partial_velocity(body) for body in bl]
    335 
    336         # Compute fr_star in two components:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\mechanics\kane.py in get_partial_velocity(body)
    326                 vlist = [body.masscenter.vel(N), body.frame.ang_vel_in(N)]
    327             elif isinstance(body, Particle):
--> 328                 vlist = [body.point.vel(N),]
    329             else:
    330                 raise TypeError('The body list may only contain either '

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\physics\vector\point.py in vel(self, frame)
    453         if not (frame in self._vel_dict):
    454             raise ValueError('Velocity of point ' + self.name + ' has not been'
--> 455                              ' defined in ReferenceFrame ' + frame.name)
    456         return self._vel_dict[frame]
    457 

ValueError: Velocity of point P has not been defined in ReferenceFrame A
```

Comment: The tuple error occurs when `ipython` attempts to print some object.  You don't show enough of the traceback to identify what that is.  The traceback for the second error is also incomplete since you don't show where `P` is defined, or the `ReferenceFrame `A`.

Comment: You are correct it is an `ipython` error. I removed the `init_printing()` and that allowed me to run the computation. I'm still unclear what the issue is. but at least I can run the model.